# php user registration num rows not working

Tags: php, mysql, methods

I know this question is already asked so many times. i am a newbie and i dont know why mysqli_num_row is not working.Even i tried procedural method of calling and OO method. still the count is 0. help me out, thanks in advance. excuses if any wrong in question.

EDITED:
I made a mistake on posting this question , Email is not encrypted. so i am removing the encryption on email. but the script is still not working.

```
<html>
<body>
     <h1 user registration </h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
            Email: <input name="ema" type="text" >  <br>
            Password: <input name="pwd" type="password" required> <br>
            <input value="submit" type="submit">
    </form> 
 <?php 
        require_once("connect.php"); 
        @$email = $_POST['ema'];    
        @$password = hash('sha512' , $_POST['pwd']);
        // SELECTING THE USER
            $sql = " SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ema = '$email' and pwd = '$password' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            if ($result)
            {
                echo "code is working" ;
                $count = $result->num_rows;
                echo $count;
            }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you actually seeing the `Code is working0` being echoed or? - Also I'd strongly recommend that you don't use `@` to handle errors, fix the errors instead of ignoring them, use `isset();` or `empty();`

Comment: yes it is showing exactly code is working0.... and users table has 2 rows

Comment: thats just showing undefined variable or index which is correctly synced with field names and i dont know why it is generating warnings? so can you exactly tell me whats the error here

Comment: @Digitalgo maybe it's showing the right info. Your database table may have millions rows. But if you write a query using conditions which doesn't match any of the rows then it's going to show `0` rows. check if user input email and password matches with your database. Try debugging using `var_dump($email); var_dump($password);` And are you intentionally hashing email or unintentionally??

Comment: @asif rahaman user table has only two rows, email is matching, but just now i check the sha 512 encryption retrieving the password with extra 21 characters. if i look the same in db that 21 characters are missing. will try udpating with new values and intiamte if any errors arise. thanks for your answer

Comment: @AsifRahaman i was using unintentionally, i changed the db var char of password and  made a new user , it fetched :) num rows 1. but can anybody tell me what is the length of sha 512 , i dont understand which is meant by 64 bits

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WANRING**: SHA512 is not a suitable password hashing algorithm. It's very quick to compute and any attacker can easily crack common passwords within seconds, especially considering you haven't even salted it. Learn about [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) if you insist on writing your own login system which is *strongly* discouraged.

Comment: It seems ,one should be expert if they are making their own encryption methods right @tadman?

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the PHP error-suppressing `@` operator without good reason. Errors are usually a sign of severe problems in your code that must be addressed for things to work normally.

Comment: Sorry to hit you with so many warnings here but this short chunk of code is so full of serious problems I can't not mention them. Yes, if you're writing an encryption method you must have a doctorate in cryptography or you'll get something wrong, I'm not even kidding here. Even experts make huge mistakes, that's why they always have their code reviewed by others. If you're *using* an encryption library you should still know how cryptography works, which means you've at least read [the Bruce Schneider book](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/) on the subject.

Comment: @tadman no problem with your suggestion and beloved warnings, can i deploy encryption methods after attending coursera cryptography part 1 and 2?

Comment: What are you encrypting? What purpose does your encryption serve? The reason I ask is because a lot of amateurs think it's some kind of magical lock when in fact if you leave the key laying around it ends up [being self-defeating](http://i.imgur.com/7RSislS.jpg).

Comment: @tadman I am encrypting the user details and for site protection.

Comment: You're probably doing it wrong. My advice: Don't encrypt anything yet. When it comes time for encryption, hire a professional security audit team to make specific recommendations that are appropriate for the type of data you're handling. They'll also review your code for other vulnerabilities that encryption won't help you with if you decrypt everything within your code and your code has leaks.

Comment: By the way, if someone's solved your problem, just flag their answer as accepted when you can. That's the official mechanism for marking as "solved".

Comment: Instead of assuming you are not going to get any data returned. Assume you are and always fetch it. You have to detect end of data anyway. Now, there is no need to ever bother testing for `num_rows` when using a select query. And testing the actual returned data always works.

Answer (score 0):

You first fetch rows

```
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$count = $row->num_rows;
```

Comment: what are you getting in $row ?

Comment: Actually when i tried your code directly, it shown me a error " Trying to get a property of non object" so i called by procedural method and it is showing same 0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing up object oriented and procedural styles. Since you have used the procedural function in the previous line **mysqli_query**, I suggest you use **mysqli_num_rows** instead of $result->num_rows

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
```

Use this as a reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.num-rows-examples

Comment: same result bro, result set has 0 rows

Comment: That explains that it doesn't have any SQL syntax error. It's probably a logical error somewhere. Are email and password both being hashed and inserted during registration?